# PHP and Active Directory

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, centos7, php-7

I am attempting to do a simple bind to my active directory server off of a CentOS 7.6 server running apache and php 7.2.

```
<?php

$username = 'tester@domain.com';
$password = 'password';
$ldap=ldap_connect('ldap.domain.com');
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
if ($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $username, $password)) {
    echo "ok";
}
else{
    echo "ldap_error: " . ldap_error($ldap);
    ldap_get_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err);
    echo "ldap_get_option: $err";
}
```

I receive the following error:

> ldap_error: Can't contact LDAP serverldap_get_option:

I ran the script from command line using 'php -f' and it comes back with 'ok' as intended. Any help getting this to run in the browser would be great.

Comment: Can you post `URI ldap` from `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf ` ?

Comment: The file does not exist?

Comment: #
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/openldap/certs